# In which time complexity operates the Savings algorithm for the TSP?

Tags: reference-request, vehicle-routing, computational-complexity, traveling-salesman, heuristics

In which time complexity operates the Savings algorithm from [Clarke and Wright](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/167703.pdf?casa_token=k_vTQBHsuy0AAAAA:0whMlhcAW4BsEjLHs1uFWM1xnd4F2n0ZETqM1QKB-8QL72zhJplTT3tueN0C-P0l8Y90baTS4rMLVZFkaBecYujZ-A4OGUhemIHvxdgwCKASd9yiCOuA) for the TSP? I mean the parallel version of Savings. I think it is in $\mathcal O(|V|\log|V|)$ with V as vertex/node because the most complex operation is sorting the savings which operate in this time for, e.g. Quicksort. The rest operates, I think, in linear time. Is this right, and is there something on the internet that covers this?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to read the paper DIFFERENT VERSIONS OF THE SAVINGS METHOD FOR THE TIME LIMITED VEHICLE ROUTING PROBLEM[[1]](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fff6/e633081358f92f9431b6247e1e8a6b8a07b9.pdf) which gives time complexities between $O(n^3)$ and $O(n^2\log(n))$ note that in these complexity analysis the number of nodes not nodes as $n$. The reason why it is $n^2$ and not $n$ is this part of the algorithm:
[image] [Taken from EOR 151 – Lecture 18 Savings Algorithm page 1](http://courses.ieor.berkeley.edu/ieor151/lecture_notes/ieor151_lec18.pdf)

The number of savings grows $O(n^2)$ (actually like $n(n+1)/2$) so sorting that leads to $O(n^2\log(n^2)) = O(2n^2\log(n)) = O(n^2\log(n))$ time complexity unless a non-comparison based sorting like trie/radix/couting sort is used.

Comment: V is the set of vertices or nodes. So n=|V|. This would not agree with the complexity that I proposed. Why does the sorting take longer than O(|V|log|V|)?

Comment: Sorry i confused vertices for edges.

Comment: @Theodeo my newest edit should make it clear while sorting takes $O(|s|*log(|s|))$ where $|s|$ is the number of savings and $|s|$ is in $O(n^2)$